# Муки модератора

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация

После поста с предложением об отставке модератора и прочитав комментарии членов сообщества, решил обсудить с вами будни модерации и как это можно и нужно упростить.

Для начала предлагаю посмотреть на SO глазами модератора, скриншот выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева синеньким "150" - означает количество тревог которые модератору необходимо рассмотреть, справа оранжевым число "6" - количество правок предложенных коллегами. Там есть и другие кнопочки/иконки, но они в данном контексте пока неважны.

Давайте внимательно посмотрим какого рода тревоги необходимо рассмотреть модератору - смотрим чуть ниже и видим разного рода [некропосты](https://lurkmore.co/%CD%E5%EA%F0%EE%EF%EE%F1%F2) 3-x, 4-x, а то и 5-ти летней давности...

Но не все так плохо. Свежие конечно же есть:
[image: Еще один скриншот]

Одна вот только проблема, они генерируются неким "Дух сообщества" (выделен на скриншоте красной рамкой). Скорее всего это робот, правила работы этого робота мне неведомы, равно как и зачем для чего это делается. КПД работы робота крайне низкий, я обычно на действия робота почти ничего не отвечаю - мне как то неудобно общаться/бороться с роботом. Я все таки человек :)

Большинство тревог (не считал, но навскидку минимум 2/3 или даже 4/5 это тревоги поднимаемые роботом). Робот сам закрывает некоторые темы, сам поднимает тревоги, занимается некропостингом и проч. темными делишками.

При этом в этих 150 тревогах теряются те самые полезные 5-10 тревог поднятые коллегами.

Теперь конструктив:

1. Необходимо ввести мораторий на некропостинг, по русски говоря, запретить трогать (редактировать/поднимать флаги/закрывать/открывать) посты с возрастом более 2-х лет. Комментировать и голосовать пожалуйста.
2. Надо что-то решить с этим роботом @Духсообщества, либо убить его, либо изменить правила работы или что самое лучшее тревоги поднятые роботом отмечать как то по другому, чтобы модератор в первую очередь обращал внимание на человеческие проблемы, а не на выдумки робота (пусть даже очень интеллектуального).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Робот не виноват и темными делишками не промышляет.

Окинем взглядом боковую панель с фильтрами.

[image: фильтры]

Все тревоги от *Духа сообщества* **уже** отмечены по-другому и попадают в категории с надписью *(автоматически)*:

- *Закрыто без комментариев (автоматически)* - это вопросы, по которым уже вынесено решение о закрытии сообществом в очереди проверки.
- *Спорная рецензия низкого качества (автоматически)* (они же *больше голосов за удаление, чем за 'выглядит хорошо'*) - появляются при противоречивых оценках на ревью, как описал @PashaPash. Требуют большего внимания - сообщество не определилось, нужно помочь.
- *вопрос необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством (автоматически)* - вопрос получил слишком низкую оценку качества.
- *слишком длинный (автоматически)*
- *слишком много комментариев (автоматически)* - робот намекает на необходимость выкинуть портянку комментариев в отдельный чат.
- ну и изредка *вандализм*

Те *"5-10 тревог поднятых коллегами"*, которые требуют наиболее быстрого реагирования, попадают в категории *cпам или оскорбление*, *другое…*, *не является ответом* и *отметки комментариев*. Их легко увидеть.

Что до моратория на некропостинг, некроправки и некротревоги - это прямо противоречит миссии сайта. Старый вопрос вполне имеет право неожиданно получить новую жизнь. Сейчас есть много старых неотвеченных вопросов, и среди них, наверняка, немало тех, на которые можно написать хороший ответ. Это, вероятно, уже не поможет вопрошающему, но поможет будущим пользователям.

Некроправки хоть и "пачкают" главную страницу служат улучшению качества контента в целом.

Некротревоги тоже нужны: бесполезное и некачественное должно естественным образом отмирать, независимо от срока давности.

Comment: Я не говорил, о том, вообще не надо трогать старые вопросы. Голосовать комментировать пожалуйста - не надо поднимать на них тревоги, открывать и закрывать их - речь то об этом.

Answer (score 12):

Спасибо за инсайт :)

Поднятые роботом тревоги это, судя по всему, посты прошедшие через цепочку:

1. поставлена тревога "низкого качества" или "не является ответом" *человеком* (на старый пост) или роботом (на новый, но короткий или заминусованый)
2. пост попал в очередь very low quality
3. его там просмотрели минимум 5 *человек*
4. минимум два из них нажало "выглядит нормально"
5. минимум 3 нажало "удалить"

Движок сайта в замешательстве - автоматом удалить нельзя, но и голоса 3-4 голоса за "надо удалить!" просто так выбросить нельзя. И движок перебрасывает пост на рассмотрение модератора.

Эту очередь создает не робот, а люди - частично те, кто при просмотре очереди допускает ошибки (пропускает мертвые ответы-ссылки, например), частично те, кто просто гребет против правил (двое таких проверяющих -> и вы получаете 20 постов в очереди на ревью в день).

Сайт явно поощеряет пользователей расставлять тревоги на вопросах и ответах. Причем массово - тут даже бедж есть за 500 тревог, который, внезапно, учитывается при выборах модераторов. Причем чем больше тревог участник ставит, тем больше он их может поставить. Я, например, могу поставить 80 тревог в день (хотя реально только однин раз поставил больше 70, ради беджа, каюсь).

Какая-то часть этих тревог обязательно будет спорной и попадет к вам на ревью. Разбор спорных, насколько я понимаю, это и есть основная обязанность модератора на SO :(. До вас они доходят только в случае, когда остальные участники не смогли обработать тревогу *сами*, и требуюется ваше решение.

Из моих - это около 20%, и, насколько я понял, это среднее значение для SO.

В любом случае, эти 150 тревог прямо инициированы людьми, а не машиной. И этих людей гораздо больше, чем тех, кто просто ткнул кнопку "написать напрямую модератору".

---

На мой взгляд, мораторий на некропостинг прямо противоречит основной идее сайта - накоплению знаний.

Если для старого *хорошего* неотвеченного вопроса есть нормальный ответ - почему я не должен его дать? Потому что топикастеру это не поможет? Я пишу ответы не ради топикастера. И не ради плюсиков.

Если старый оффтопичный вопрос висит открытым - его надо закрыть (не обязательно удалить). Хотя бы ради того, чтобы новички не пытались на него отвечать, и не ловили минусы.

У вас есть historical lock - вы можете просто заблокировать все старые оффтопичные вопросы (сразу от всего, включая ответы, закрытие и удаление). Все неоффтопичные - я бы предложил оставить на усмотрение сообщества. Каждый голосует как он хочет (@Vlad?)

Запрещать поднимать флаги на старые ответы-ссылки, на старые посылания в гугл (который ведет обратно на SO, на этот самый вопрос) - нет, спасибо.