# Выборы модератора сообщества 2017

Tags: поддержка, выборы

**С радостью спешу сообщить, что с этой недели стартуют выборы модераторов сообщества 2017!**

В этом году нам необходимо выбрать *двух новых модераторов*, которые будут помогать нам, сообществу, поддерживать содержимое сайта на высочайшем уровне, а участникам жить дружно, без ссор.

Выборы модераторов сообщества состоят из трех этапов:

1. С этого момента – первый этап, [сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5983/).
2. 9 октября начнется второй этап — этап номинирования, когда участники будут выдвигать свои кандидатуры, а сообщество голосовать за наиболее понравившихся.
3. Ровно через неделю после номинирования, 16 октября, начинается, собственно, этап выборов, который может состоять либо из двух стадий, либо из одной, в зависимости от количество выдвинувшихся кандидатов.

Пожалуйста, посетите официальную страницу выборов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election для получения дополнительной информации и принимайте участие!

Если у Вас есть вопросы по процессу проведения выборов или по кандидатам в модераторы, задавайте их здесь, на Мете — только убедитесь, что ваши вопросы имеют метку [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).

Подробнее о выборах модераторов:

- [Что такое выборы в модераторы сообщества и как они работают?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1983/)
- [Каковы обязательные требования для кандидата в модераторы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1998/)
- [Каким критериям должен соответствовать участник сообщества для избрания в модераторы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1398/)

### Отзывы настоящих модераторов

- [Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5986/6).
- [Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5987/6).
- [PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6015/6)

### Отзывы участников сообщества

- [D-side](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6022/6)

Comment: Почему не трёх?

Comment: @Qwertiy три уже было.

Comment: @Qwertiy по согласованию с текущей командой модераторов.

Comment: Двух новых, т.е. всего двое будет или плюс два новых?

Comment: @edem было три, станет пять, плюс Nicolas – он сотрудник.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну Nicolasа можно не считать :-)

Answer (score 14):

## Я *не* планирую выдвигаться в модераторы

...что само по себе мало кого интересует.

А вот причины, по которым я не хочу выдвигаться, могут убедить кого-то ещё отказаться от этой затеи:

- При наличии ромба **ваши голоса** на закрытие вопросов и в проверках, а также тревоги на комментариях **будут решающими**. Вы перестанете быть частью электората, вы станете единоличным судьёй и палачом, с возможностью выносить единогласные (свои) решения по вопросам, которые в обычных ситуациях требуют голосов 3-5 человек. Теоретически, лечится заведением второго аккаунта "для участия в демократии", но работать с двумя сразу будет довольно неудобно.
- Обретя ромб, вы *в глазах прохожих* станете виновником всех проблем в правилах Stack Overflow на русском и абстрактным адресатом просьб "админ, забань их плз, чего они не отвечают нормально". И **вам иногда будут грубить**, когда вы будете силой заставлять кого-то соблюдать правила. Нечасто, но когда будут, скорее всего довольно крепко. Имейте в виду, нарушение правил в отношении модератора карается точно так же, как нарушение в отношении любого другого участника.
- У вас будет **доступ к информации, распространять которую не разрешается**, как бы ни хотелось. Нужно будет следить, что она не утекает на ваших скриншотах. А также сдерживаться и не рассказывать о забавных ситуациях, найденных в ней. Соблазн будет.
- Вам придётся **поступать в соответствии со справкой и решениями на Мете, даже если вы с ними не согласны**. Хотя (а) с такими взглядами попасть на должность модератора может быть непросто, и (б) возможно, это несогласие лучше преодолеть, убедив сообщество в вашей правоте, или осознав доводы в пользу текущего положения.

Comment: Жаль. Думаю, вы бы хорошим модератором стали.

Comment: Большое спасибо! К слову, скажу, что первый элемент списка для меня видится действительно проблемой.

Comment: _вы станете единоличным судьёй и палачом_ - это ж вроде плюс, разве нет? :-D

Comment: **Пункт 1** имеет место. Теперь очень редко голосую за закрытие первым. Не то чтобы это был большой минус для меня: в очереди проверки с большой вероятностью не пропустят мусор. **Пункт 2**: "админ, забань их плз" почти не встречается, а вот от "вам иногда будут грубить" никуда не деться.
**Пункт 3** не выглядит большой проблемой. До сих пор не встречал ничего "такого", про что возникло бы желание кому-то показывать. То, что относится к личным данным пользователе главным образом сводится к  email/ip/времени посещения. Нет ни забавных ситуаций, ни соблазнов.

Comment: @Nofate (3) мыслите шире. Когда в сообществе **драмы**, модераторам нельзя раскрывать, за что кого забанили и кто кого и на что тревогнул.

Comment: @D-side, а обычным участникам (при своём стандартно-ограниченном доступе) можно, если они эту драму успели сохранить в интернет-архив, либо себе на жёсткий диск?

Comment: @Arhad подобные ограничения, насколько я знаю, есть только в модераторском соглашении. Видимо, можно.

Comment: **Пункт 3**: поддерживаю Nofate. В личных данных нет ничего увлекательного. Помню их ровно полминуты, пока сравниваю учетные записи. **Пункт 1**: да, всё верно. Но изредка бывает нужно такое силовое решение. Ещё только модератор может отменить неверно поставленную тревогу «спам» — её нередко ставят на вопросы со ссылкой на сайт автора, где надо проблему решить, либо на ссылки-рекомендации.

Comment: **Ещё пункт 1**: в обычных ситуациях вы всегда можете дождаться, когда на вопросе уже будет 4 голоса за закрытие. **Пункт 2**: пару раз в неделю пингуют из чата всех подряд модераторов. В последнее время стало меньше этого, хотя бы объединять учетки сразу просят Николаса.

Comment: **И ещё пункт 1**: зато вы сможете обучать других участников, обрабатывая их тревоги. Нередко вместо тревоги «спам» пишут в тревоге «это спам, удалите». Вместо закрытия — пишут «вопрос непонятен» или «нужен код». На ошибочный ответ ставят «не является ответом». На комментарий с конструктивной критикой ставят «невежливый или оскорбительный». Во всех этих случаях участникам нужна адекватная обратная связь.

Comment: @D-side предлагаю передумать )

Comment: @D-side Вы просто описали мою жизнь... нет, мое существование :) много лет назад на посту одного из координаторов в сети FidoNet, если кто еще помнит такую...

Comment: @Harry не помню (в ту пору у меня еще не было интернета), но знаю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ууууу, как все запущено :) Это уже потом появились всякие Fido over TCP, а изначально - шипящие модемы, выкачивающие почту, чтение/ответы offline (ну, кто хотел (и мог) online - на BBS'ках)...

Answer (score 11):

`<торжественная_речь>`

Работа модератора - это, своего рода, community payback на *мета*-уровне (<sub><sup>*no pun intended*</sup></sub>). Конечно, когда-то все мы, столкнувшись с трудностями в мире программировании, искали помощи у коллег со всего мира. А теперь, набравшись опыта, помогаем другим. Это вклад знаниями. Но важно также помогать людям создать условия, чтобы этот обмен знаниями произошел, вносить социальный или организационный вклад.  Думаю, это - то, для чего модераторы в конечном счете нужны здесь, на StackOverflow.

`</торжественная_речь>`

Ладно, спустимся на землю. Модераторство - не сахар. Куча людей с клавиатурами, которые никогда не видели друг друга в лицо - отличная среда для конфликтов. Кроме того, где есть правила, всегда есть недовольные правилами. Свое недовольство они как правило вываливают на "ромбовых". И к этому надо быть готовым. Старожилы нашего чата помнят про [модераторский-произвол](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb), *ХАМЬЕ*, *второзаконие*,  *Nofate должна уйти*, *какой ваш регистрационный номер в РКН?* и другие неприятные случаи из жизни модераторов. Эмоции, которые могут возникнуть в такой момент, нужно уметь отключать. И привыкнуть к тому, что придется забанить за нарушение активного участника, еще полчаса назад мило беседовавшего в чате. И ловить минусы и вандализм в свои ответы. И встретить участника-пародиста с твоим юзерпиком. И в сотый раз объяснять (не всегда) взрослым людям, что некоторые вещи делать нехорошо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В остальном, если вы можете получать удовольствие, помогая другим людям, модератором вам быть понравится: отвечайте на Мете, разгребайте тревоги, ловите клоноводов, украшайте тексты, пополняйте знания попутно узнавая много интересного из вопросов и ответов.

На этом фоне в новых участниках модераторской команды хотелось бы видеть самообладание, понимание наших правил (и их главенства над личным мнением), хорошее владение русским и английским языками и немного эстетства.

Comment: Добавлю: самая жесть вообще не попадает в публичный чат. В личные сообщения порой пишут довольно неприятные вещи.

Comment: @NickVolynkin на томик мемуаров наскребётся?

Comment: Картинка напомнила мне про «[муки модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1787/208074)».

Comment: @alexolut в мемуары обычно пишут что-то значимое, а я не придаю значения таким сообщениям. Пересматриваю их только когда нужно повторно забанить участника — тогда история нашего общения действительно играет роль. Если человек демонстрирует способность понимать и договариваться, то мы продолжаем договариваться. Если нет — срок бана растет экспоненциально.

Comment: _второзаконие_? я уже и не помню такого

Answer (score 11):

Хотелось бы видеть среди новых модераторов участников, знакомых с [теорией модерации](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)

- Хорошо ориентирующихся в решениях, принятых за последние годы на мете и готовых применять эти решения, включая те, с которыми вы не до конца согласны.
- Готовых пожертвовать временем на написание интересных вопросов и ответов ради сомнительного удовольствия разгребания очереди.

Если у вас нордический характер, вы не против проводить за сомнительными флагами по пол часа в день, и вас не слишком огорчит застывшая на одной отметке репутация - записывайтесь в модераторы.

Comment: Почему репутация застывает?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev потому что модерация отнимает время, которое до этого участник тратил на ответы на вопросы :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev модератор не зарабатывает репутацию сам. Он заставляет её зарабатывать других :) Производитель удочек, так сказать.

Comment: @D-side ну как сказать... с тем, сколько оффтопа и вопросов ссылок было удалено, некоторые участники довольно-таки сильно потеряли репутацию от действий модераторов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне казалось, что такие вещи обычно уходят в минус, и их удаление скорее возвращает репу.

Comment: @D-side ох да что вы, истории об обучении детей программированию и карьерных потугах очень популярны.

Comment: @NickVolynkin помню только один случай, когда подобное отобрало много репы, т. к. вопрос утащили на Мету. Поднялся шум и решили, что этого делать не стоило, надо было блокировать вопрос. И я под впечатлением, что в минус такие вопросы уходят чаще, как оффтопик.

Answer (score 10):

## Мы ждём, что будущие модераторы будут:

### 1. Разбирать очередь

Сейчас основная сложность — разбирать очередь тревог. Бывают довольно нетривиальные тревоги, на них уходит много времени. Поэтому в последнее время мы стали разбирать очередь медленнее, чем полтора года назад.
Нужны кандидаты, которые возьмут на себя часть очереди и будут вместе с нами разбираться в подковерных интригах и запутанных взаимоотношениях участников.
Если вы чувствуете в себе силы выполнять довольно-таки скучную, а иногда совсем неприятную работу по наведению порядка — пожалуйста, выдвиньте свою кандидатуру на выборы.

### 2. Оказывать поддержку на Мете

Также здорово, если вы будете оказывать поддержку участникам на Мете. Периодически бывают вопросы, на которые нужно дать понятный, полный и обоснованный ответ. Нам кажется, что если автор такого ответа отмечен ромбом, то это оказывает дополнительное внушающее воздействие, особенно на новичков.
Хорошие ответы пишутся долго и нам не хватает времени отвечать на каждый вопрос.
Если вы умеете и любите спокойно и подробно объяснять — пожалуйста, выдвиньте свою кандидатуру на выборы.

### 3. Проявлять дружелюбие и терпение

В последнее время я нередко вижу, что опытные и «высокореповые» участники относятся к новичкам довольно-таки пренебрежительно. Если вы не согласны с принципами, описанными в статьях «[Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)» и «[Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly)» — пожалуйста, не выдвигайте свою кандидатуру.

Nick Volynkin, настоящий модератор. ;)

Comment: То есть цели перед довыбранными модераторами серьёзно отличаются от [целей нынешних модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4209/208074)?

Comment: @Arhad от моих заявленных перед выборами наивных целей отличаются. С моими текущими целями совпадают.

Comment: @Arhad прочитал вопрос по вашей ссылке. Насколько я понимаю, там вообще речь о возможностях модерации для всех участников. В обучение новичков вкладываются очень многие участники.

Comment: А обязательно быть модератором, чтобы помогать в разборе очереди, или достаточно иметь 2-3К репутации?

Comment: @DaemonHK не сразу заметил ваш вопрос, отвечаю сейчас. Тревоги конфиденциальны и модераторы не имеют права никому даже говорить, что некто А поставил тревогу на сообщение Б. Поэтому очередь тревог доступна только модераторам. Но 2-3 тысячи достаточно, чтобы [разбирать очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review). Это тоже полезная и нужная для сайта работа.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, хотя да, согласен, модераторы ведь подписывают "о неразглашении", чего от рядовых участников вряд ли дождешься))

Comment: @DaemonHK прямо на бумажке не подписываем, но жмем кнопку «Принять». Подробностей не помню, давно было.