# Давайте добавим трёх модераторов?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, выборы

Предлагаю чуть-чуть изменить данные выборы и выбрать троих модераторов вместо двоих. Почему?

- Объективность выборов не поменяется, просто вместо двоих кандидатов (ТОП-2) отсеем троих (ТОП-3).
- Ничего изобретать и менять не нужно.
- Ещё одни руки не помешают и следующие выборы можно будет проводить позже (так как сообщество всё больше и больше разрастается).
- Изобилие достойных кандидатов.
- Эффективность модерации ещё больше возрастёт за счёт большего количества человек.
- Никому не придётся платить или тратиться — модерация дело добровольное.
- Система голосования предлагает и так три голоса, поэтому три кандидата будут смотреться тоже гармонично.
- Особенно будет это уместно если разрыв между вторым и третьим местом будем небольшим и будет обидно, когда кто не прошёл с маленьким разрывом.

Comment: 1) Нет. 2) Поздно. 3) Нет.

Comment: поздновато вы спохватились; возможно, знай заранее, что вакантрых мест 3, было бы больше выдвиженцев

Comment: ...коней на переправе не меняют

Comment: Давайте возьмём M? M — мало, возьмём N.

Comment: @Abyx, не поздно. На ptSO четвёртое место уже при подведении итогов (т. е. после окончания голосования) добавили.

Comment: @mymedia, см выше.

Comment: @PauloBerezini, см выше.

Comment: @Qwertiy ...на что смотреть?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, на комментарий про ptSO.

Comment: @Qwertiy вижу, на ptSO был такой прецедент, дальше что?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, получается им можно, а нам поздно?

Comment: @Qwertiy мало ли что другие делают, не надо брать плохой пример.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper А чем плохой пример? Никто от этого не должен пострадать. От того, что зараннее это не сделано не значит, что это плохо.

Answer (score 5):

Лучше меньше, да лучше! В любом случае — [текущий состав модераторов решил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5985/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-2017#comment22909_5985), что им достаточно пока двоих. Ну и предлагать это когда выборы уже начались, довольно странно. Жернова уже раскручены на полную. За неожиданность вопроса — "пять", за несвоевременность — "два".

Comment: Если бы не было столько хороших и готовых браться за работу кандидатов, я бы не ставил это вопрос, а знать зараннее сколько будет адекватных кандидатов проблематично. Тем более первые кандидаты (в основном) не сильно меня вдохновляли за них голосовать. Поэтому, по моему мнению, вопрос своевременный. Тем более, я его ставлю почти в момент голосования, то есть когда неизвестно кто будет третим, а не по факту свершившегося голосования. Что даёт мне право полагать, что это никак не отразится на процессе голосования.

Answer (score 3):

Почему бы и нет :)

На других сайтах, вроде, обычно выбирают по 3. А что касается того, что поздно, на ptSO добавляли четвёртую позицию уже после завершения голосования, так что прецедент есть, и никогда не поздно!

Answer (score 2):

На прошлых выборах, строго говоря, добавился один модератор. Были Nofate и Barmaley, стали Nofate, PashaPash и я.

На этих выборах добавится два модератора, это уже немало.

Comment: Ну там же не добавление было - были временные модераторы и их заменили постоянными.

Comment: @Qwertiy работоспособность Nofate не поменялась же, когда он из временного стал постоянным?

Comment: Ну я и не говорил, что поменялась)